# Run TIdeSDK app in Background

Tags: tidesdk, dock

I want to run the tideSDK app in background when user clicks the run app in background button. How can I achieve this. So that app is not showing in the front.

Is it possible to this stuff in tideSDK? Any pointers to achieve this would be Great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do

```
win.hide();
```

where `win` is a `Ti.UI.UserWindow`. When the app is hidden it is run as a background process:

[image]

(`背景處理程序` means "Background Processes")